# Java Scanner Error : Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java

I am trying to get user input but I keep getting the error: No Line Found
The line number is referencing "input = fileS.nextLine();" as the source of the error

```
System.out.print("Is this table a simple table? Please check document to confirm, If YES please Enter Y If NO please Enter N \n");
             Scanner fileS = new Scanner(System.in);

             input = fileS.nextLine();
             input = input.trim();
             input = input.toLowerCase();

             tableCount ++;
             fileS.close();
```

That is my code, I understand that if I used fileS.hasNextLine() it would avoid this error 
But
this skips the user input all together.

What am I missing here?

The scanner is in a public function

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this code works fine for me. could you post stacktrace

Comment: Maybe your standard input is redirected. Which IDE are you using? Could you provide more context?

Comment: How do I trace the stack? and I am using Eclipse What other info do you need?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
 at advMrkupEdit.tabler(advMrkupEdit.java:815) That is the error the 815 line is the code i posted and the other error is the function call with the scanner in it
 at advMrkupEdit.main(advMrkupEdit.java:266)

Comment: Create a new test class, add a main method and try to run your code from there and tell us if it is working in this new context.

Comment: The code works in a tester class.

Comment: So, the problem seems to be the surrounding code. I'd suggest you describe your `advMrkupEdit` class. Is this a GUI element?

Comment: There are no GUI elements, the class is to take some user input for direction in editing files. I think the problem is coming from my main function where I am reading in a file using other input streams

Answer (score 2):

You should read the input this way:

```
while(fileS.hasNextLine())
{
    //Your operations here
}
```

When you do

> fileS.nextLine();

It will try to read, and if no line is found, it will throw the exception. Also look for

> fileS.close()

in your code file before reading. If you are closing it before the reading operation, you can't reopen it again and it will throw the exception. I think this is the most probable cause, because I had it a few weeks ago :P

Comment: Very True but as I said before I tried the while loop which is great because it skips the error but it also skips the user input. And again correct about the closing the input stream then trying to re-open it! But that isn't the case here... I have no closing inputstreams before my code stated above. I am reviewing all my code... at this point i am thinking I have a syntax error or some other code mismatch error. Great answer though for others who read this because this will most likely fix their issue.

Comment: Maybe look for other closing Scanner lines. My issue was 'cause I had two Scanners and in one method I closed one. As I read somewhere in the web, closing one InputStream(System.in) will cause to close ALL the ISs in the program execution.

Answer (score 1):

well, instead of `nextLine()` you should use `hasNextLine()` almost always. But you are skipping the input because your `System.in` might not be pointing to `console` or any `inputstream` that can take any input or open an `inputstream`. That's why its not working at all in case of `hasNextLine`, while `nextLine()` being a forced method to read even if there is no data, is expecting an input but being not able to get that its throwing exception. may be you should check where your `System.in` is pointing.

you can manually set it as `setIn(Console())` also you can check whether `console()` is non-null.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are calling the Scanner(System.in) inside a loop, try to put it to the top or before any loop. That's why the test works and the working is not.

```
Is this table a simple table? Please check document to confirm, If YES please Enter Y If NO please Enter N 
y
Is this table a simple table? Please check document to confirm, If YES please Enter Y If NO please Enter N 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
    at ScannerIssue.main(ScannerIssue.java:11)
```

..

```
        while(true){
        System.out.print("Is this table a simple table? Please check document to confirm, If YES please Enter Y If NO please Enter N \n");
        Scanner fileS = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input = fileS.nextLine();
        input = input.trim();
        input = input.toLowerCase();

//        tableCount ++;
        fileS.close();
        }
```

Above's code is causing the error
Move the Scanner fileS = new Scanner(System.in); to the start of the method or class scope.

You can use something like this:

```
Scanner fileS = new Scanner(System.in); //moved out of the loop
            while (true) {
                System.out
                        .print("Is this table a simple table? Please check document to confirm, If YES please Enter Y If NO please Enter N \n");
                String input = fileS.nextLine();
                input = input.trim();
                input = input.toLowerCase();
                // tableCount ++;
                if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            fileS.close(); //moved out of the loop
            System.out.println("Good bye!");
        }
```

The resoult would be:

```
Is this table a simple table? Please check document to confirm, If YES please Enter Y If NO please Enter N 
Y
Is this table a simple table? Please check document to confirm, If YES please Enter Y If NO please Enter N 
A
Is this table a simple table? Please check document to confirm, If YES please Enter Y If NO please Enter N 
N
Good bye!
```

Answer (score 0):

If it works the first time you loop through it, the following could be the problem.

From Java DOCs:

When a Scanner is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the Closeable interface.

Which means it closes the System.in

Remove `fileS.close();` and your program should work fine!